# Matching an image pixel by pixel with the captured screen in asp.net window forms

Tags: asp.net, winforms, colors, pixel

I am working to find an image(3 x 3) in the screen captured(1366 x 768).
Actually, the screen captured is the browser's screenshot in which a website is opened.
I'm finding the image and calculating the X and Y coordinates.

I'm not facing any problem with the code it's working fine and giving me the exact X,Y coordinates where it finds the exact pixels(3 x 3) RGB values in the captured screen. Note that it finds the image by comparing the RGB value of each pixel.

The problem is that each website creating the different pixel format and my image(3 x 3) is working only with the specific website. I want to make it work with all websites.

**This is the image I need to find:**

[image]

Below you can see that two different websites have the different pixel format for the same word.

--> The below both screenshots were taken by the process -> open a website -> ctrl + f -> type "Home"

--> Written RGB Values are only of Green color.

**It's able to find the above image(3 x 3) in the below one:**
[image: Image 1]

**It's NOT able to find the above image(3 x 3) in the below one. Because the pixel format is completely different.**
[image: Image 2]

Is there any way to override this problem?

I can create a new image(3 x 3 or of any size) to find in the captured screen. But that should work with all websites.

Comment: You are comparing raw rgb values. What is pixel format has to do with anything?

Comment: The pixel format of 3x3 image is appearing in the first image but not in the second one.

Comment: If you are trying to compare a lets say 32 bit depth image with a 16 one of cource it wont work. eg if the pixel has r=100, g=100 and b=100 you wont find it in the second one. Both need to be the same format. What is the problem?

Comment: The image(3x3) is the 24 bit depth bitmap image. And it's working fine for the first "Home" button image. Because it has the same pixels as my 3x3 image has.

But 2nd "Home" button image doesn't have the same pixels as 3x3 image has, that's why it's not finding.

Comment: *...that's why it's not finding.* you answered your own question

Comment: haha, That's not my question. My question is to fnd a way to make it working with all website. Is there any way?

Comment: If yours it is 24(8, 8, 8) bits it means 255 values for 3 colors. Lets take only red for a moment. Second image only 56. So it is roughly 1-5. You can map (0-4)->0, (5-9)->1,(10-14)->2....etc. If dest image red pixel is 2 and yours red is 10-14 it is a match.

Comment: It probably wont work but you can try...

Comment: I'm not understanding your point. Can you please elaborate?